# react-native switch crashes on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use a switch in react-native (0.63.4).

```
 const trackColor = { false: defaultSwitchOffColor, true: TuColor.Primary };
...
<Switch value={isTeamComparisonAllowed}
    trackColor={trackColor}
    onValueChange={() => this.setState({ isTeamComparisonAllowed: !isTeamComparisonAllowed })}/>
```

On iOS it runs without problems, but on Android I get an error when I call the component that contains the switch:

```
2021-01-09 16:02:27.750 27964-27964/team.trainyour.trainurteam E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'trackTintColor' of a view managed by: AndroidSwitch
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:102)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:56)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties(ViewManager.java:49)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:270)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:186)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1112)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1083)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```